# Add field to Checkout

Tags: magento2.4

I created a custom field for customer:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\MyModule\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;

class AddCustomAttributeCustomerAttribute implements DataPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface
{

    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;
    /**
     * @var CustomerSetup
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;
    /**
     * @var SetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param SetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        SetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType(Customer::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet Set */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'custom_attribute',
            [
                'label' => 'My Custom Attribute',
                'input' => 'text',
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'source' => '',
                'required' => false,
                'position' => 333,
                'visible' => true,
                'system' => false,
                'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
                'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
                'backend' => ''
            ]
        );

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'custom_attribute');
        $attribute->addData([
            'used_in_forms' => [
                 'adminhtml_customer',
                 'adminhtml_checkout',
                 'customer_account_create',
                 'customer_account_edit'
            ]
        ]);
        $attribute->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId

        ]);
        $attribute->save();

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    public function revert()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $customerSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'custom_attribute');

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [

        ];
    }
}
```

It show in the admin, I can edit... all work perfect!

But now I need add this field to Checkout.

I tried to updated the `checkout_index_index.xml` with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="custom_attribute" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress</item>
                                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/input</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.custom_attribute</item>
                                                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">My Custom Attribute</item>
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

But it doesnt show.

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if the code you share is right way or not but try the same thing with extension attribute